# Change another program's variable through c++ in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, api

I would like to change the variable of a program through c++. I'll be honest, I want to make a bot to play the game Diablo II. I have no malicious intent, I simply want to learn. Diablo II has been a favorite game of mine since I was a child, so I thought this would be a nice avenue to explore c++ and other aspects of OOP languages. Is this possible through the way it is specified, and if not (or even if it is) please give me a nudge in the right direction.

I've done some research on the topic, though it hasn't yielded much results. From what I understand, I would need to access the variables of the program through the Windows API. Which brings me to my second question: are there any tutorials or books that the great community of stackoverflow would recommend I read to learn and understand the Windows API?

Any and all advice concerning this topic or those related would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for reading and possibly responding.

M

Comment: It's very worth learning C++ to a good degree before starting with the Windows API. Anyway, Petzold's book is good. The function you're ultimately looking for is `WriteProcessMemory`, but it's not that simple.

Comment: @chris Thank you for your reply. I am by no means a master at c++, but I have had a decent amount of experience. I admit this project is definitely beyond my means, but it will allow me to research and learn more. I will most certainly check out both the book as well as the specific function you have mentioned.

M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change variables of another program, you will need the following:

**The variable's location in memory.**
If it is on the stack or a local variable, forget it.  Almost impossible to modify while the other program is executing.

**The variable's type.**
Is it double, float, integer, or a structure?

**The variable's purpose.**
What purpose is the variable?
Is this the correct variable to modify?
When is it used or when can it be modified?

You should also figure out which OS API to use to access the other program's memory.